# Orchestration are single threaded?

Tags: c#, biztalk

Can anyone confirm if a BizTalk orchestration is executed on a single thread? or multiple? During dehydration/resuming, would BizTalk engine create new thread or suspend/awake the same thread. 
I'm thinking of using Thread Context to store a unique request Id, that will be used to group activity logs in database

Thanks

Comment: is there any other option similar to [threadStatic] which will be unique for orchestration??

we cant use static has the variable should not be shared across the multiple orchestration instances

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your only guarantee is that a single shape will be executed in a single thread without interruption. The next shape might be executed on a different thread, a different processor or even a different machine!

So using ThreadContext to store data between different shapes is definitely a bad idea. There is a reason why Orchestration variables exist and why they must be serializable!

If you want to group your activity logs, use the Orchestration Instance ID, which is guaranteed to stay the same over the lifetime of the orchestration.

Comment: Thanks but passing Orchestration ID to Logging method is not a preferable option because we have to change code for 50+ services

Comment: Just to add to this. The thread executing the orchestration dies as soon as its dehydrated. Once rehydrated, it's going to execute on a different thread, potentially on a different machine. Is this a custom logging engine?

Comment: is there any other option similar to [threadStatic] which will be unique for orchestration??

we cant use static has the variable should not be shared across the multiple orchestration instances